# ¿Cómo puedo convertir este código JavaScript a TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

¿Cómo puedo convertir el siguiente código a TypeScript?

```
var array = []

array.push({
    'name': 'hola',
    'list': []
})

array[0]['list'].push('list1')
alert(array[0]['name'])
```

Comment: Seria mejor primero que quieres intentar con ese javascript, asi se puede definir mejor la solucion en Typescript

Comment: Lo tengo, leeré el objetivo del sitio web

Comment: Hola @sYsTeM, todo código `JavaScript` es código `TypeScript` por defecto, ya que `TypeScript` es un _subset_ de `JavaScript`. Será mejor que aclares a qué te refieres con _convertir_ el código. ¿Te da error? ¿quieres solo añadirle chequeo de tipos?

Comment: No obtengo ningún error en el código anterior, solo estoy tratando de **"push"** y **"alert"**, pero en TypeScript es diferente cuando trabajo con tipos

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tuve que dirigirme al [PlayGround de `TypeScript`](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play) para darme cuenta dónde estaba tu problema. Como te explicaba en los comentarios, todo código `JavaScript` es también un código `TypeScript`, ya que el segundo es un *superset* del primero. Esto hace la migración de una aplicación menos tediosa porque se puede hacer paso a paso.

Ahora, aunque `TypeScript` [es sumamente inteligente infiriendo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html) los tipos de las variables, [hay ocasiones en que esta tarea no es perfecta](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/18687). En tu caso [el único error que `TypeScript` detecta](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/FDBuEMCcAIs8Ce0C80DaBdA3COiB0ADgK4DOAFgBQDew090AduALYCmAXNAOTkD2AG3DcANHQYCAlqQAuXTMAC+ASlyR4CNAAYM+KbKJkq3fTICM3VeAFtIMynk0603Zu24ZlQA) es:

> Argument of type '"list1"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.

Intentando hacer `push` de la cadena `list1` en el array porque el mismo ha sido inferido como de tipo `never` (si declaras el array con al menos una cadena dentro, este error desaparecerá porque será inferido de la manera correcta).

Una solución alternativa para que `TypeScript` no infiera el array vacío como de tipo `never` es cambiar la forma de declarar el mismo:

```
var array = [];

array.push({
    name: 'hola',
    list: new Array()
})

array[0].list.push('list1')
alert(array[0]['name'])
```

Como ves, el código es el mismo, pero esta vez `TypeScript` ha inferido el array `list` como de tipo `any[]`y [no lanza ningún error](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=9&ssc=24&pln=1&pc=1#code/G4QwTgBOYgnhBeCBtAugbgFCenAdAA4CuAzgBYAUA3phHRAHYgC2ApgFwQDkZA9gDYguAGlr1+ASxIAXTg1YB3CAEEwMWBQCUmAL7acauMgAMqPJJmFSlLhekBGLtpD9WYaRVywTqZFyZsXKiaQA).

De todas maneras, no tiene sentido usar `TypeScript` si no vas a usar sus características, y en este caso en particular, estamos hablando de una de las características más potentes que posee, que es el tipado de variables. Así que la mejor solución es especificar qué tipo de datos contendrán `name` y `list` en cada objeto del array. Esto lo puedes lograr, como ya te explicó @JoseVelasco, creando un [type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html) o una [interface](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html) para declarar la forma de los objetos dentro de dicho array:

```
// Usando type
type Datos = {
    name: string;
    list: string[];
}

// Usando interface
interface Datos {
    name: string;
    list: string[];
}

const array: Datos[] = [];
```

En esta situación en particular (declarar la forma de un objeto), puedes usar `type` o `interface` a tu preferencia. Pero si deseas profundizar más en las diferencias entre ambos, te recomiendo leer [este post de SO en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37233735) o [este post de Medium](https://medium.com/@jesusmurfontanals/typescript-para-que-sirven-los-types-y-interfaces-y-en-que-se-diferencian-bee0af17fffa) que dejó el compañero @JoseVelasco en los comentarios, que aunque muy general, está en español y te puede dar una idea de sus diferencias.

Con este cambio, el código [ya no te lanzará error](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=6&pc=27#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCJzAewM7IN4BQyxyIcAthAFzLZhSgDmA3ESQDbB010MiMBtALqsAvgQIJMIOsjhQocAJ410WbMOQBeZMNYF5ipQDoADgFdsACwAUhEqQrVkAciuZ2cFwBo2xTty6QgSiAJQShsoCAAxCxgFgZpa2LgkAjC7hcOzQYDaRSjFCAi5klC5CoUA), porque `TypeScript` no ha tenido que inferir ninguna de las variables.

Comment: En lugar de usar `list: new Array()` podrías simplemente escribir `list: []`. Ve [esta regla](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-array-constructor) de eslint para que veas las desventajas de ese modo.

Comment: @devconcept `list: []` es el origen del problema (es como está en el código del OP y `TypeScript` lo infiere como `never`), consulta los enlaces que dejé. Por supuesto la mejor solución si se va a usar `TypeScript` es hacer uso de los tipos, pero en este caso en particular es un _workaround_ para deshacerse del error.

Comment: Correcto pero el punto de usar Typescript no es deshacerse del error creando otro problema nuevo sino crear tipado fuerte y manejar el error apropiadamente sin crear nuevos errores potenciales. Lo que quiero decir es que deberías hacer explicito que esa no es la forma recomendable de hacerlo sino la segunda que especificas en la respuesta.

Comment: @devconcept: Intentaré modificar la respuesta más tarde para que no se vaya a interpretar que no recomiendo usar el tipado en `TypeScript` (no tiene sentido usar `TypeScript` si no se va a hacer uso de una de las cosas fundamentales que el mismo brinda). Gracias por la observación.

Comment: Chapó por la explicación ElChiniNet, solo podría añadir un enlace donde se explica la diferencia entre 'interface' y 'type' ya que, aunque se usan de manera muy parecida, poseen diferentes características. [Link al artículo](https://medium.com/@jesusmurfontanals/typescript-para-que-sirven-los-types-y-interfaces-y-en-que-se-diferencian-bee0af17fffa)

Comment: Gracias @JoseVelasco, en cuanto tenga un tiempo añado el enlace y una pequeña explicación de ambos.

Answer (score 2):

Sí tienes claro el tipo de propiedades de cada objeto que contendrá el array puedes definir un "type" específico. En el caso de tu código:

```
type dataObject = {
    name: string;
    list: Array<any>;  // o Array<string> sí sólo va a contener cadenas de texto
}

var array: dataObject[] = []
```

En este caso sí intentas añadir una propiedad no definida en el tipo, recibirás el error pertinente. Por ejemplo, si tratas de añadir:

```
array.push({
    'name': 'hola',
    'surname': 'adios',
    'list': []
})
```

Verás el error (vscode en mi caso):

> Argument of type '{ 'name': string; 'surname': string; 'list': undefined[]; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'dataObject'.
>     Object literal may only specify known properties, and ''surname'' does not exist in type 'dataObject'.

Y en este caso tienes la opción de definirlo como 'opcional' de la siguiente forma:

```
type dataObject = {
    name: string;
    surname?: string;
    list: Array<any>;
}
```

Espero que te sea de ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

Hola puedes leer información detallada en este link

https://apiumhub.com/es/tech-blog-barcelona/como-migrar-de-javascript-a-typescript/

```
array: any = []

this.array.push({
    'name': 'hola',
    'list': []
});

this.array[0]['list'].push('list1')
alert(array[0]['name'])
```